# How many arrangements exist (a + b + c = 4)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, analysis, contest-math

For example,

> $a + b + c = 4$

Solving this using stars and bars You have $4$ stars and $2$ bars:

$$ x | x | xx$$ For example.

> Then what does $\binom{6}{2}$ mean? The number of arrangements of the two bars out of $6$ objects? If so, is this a general case?

Answer (score 3):

${n \choose r} = \frac{n!}{r! (n-r)!}$ is called the binomial coefficient.

It represents many possible situations in combinatorics. In this case, it represents the total number of way to order six objects, of which there is a group of $4$ identical elements (the $x$'s) and a group of $2$ identical elements (the $|$'s),

Answer (score 1):

We are distributing $4$ identical candies among $3$ kids, with some kids possibly getting no candies. For reasons I don't quite understand, I prefer to think of the distribution process as follows. I will distribute $4+3$ candies among the $3$ kids, with each kid getting **at least one** candy, and then take away $1$ candy from each kid.

So line up the $7$ candies in a row, like this:
$$\ast\quad\ast\quad\ast\quad\ast\quad\ast\quad\ast\quad\ast$$
There are $6$, that is, $4+3-1$ intercandy gaps. I will choose $2$ of these gaps to put a separator (bar) into. Then Kid A will get all the candies up to the first separator, Kid B will get the candies between the first separator and the second, and Kid C will get the candies from the second separator to the end. (And then I will take a candy from each kid.)

There are $\binom{4+3-1}{2}$ ways to **choose** the gaps into which I will put a separator. So the number of ways to distribute $7$ candies with at least $1$ to each is $\binom{6}{2}$. It follows that the number of ways to distribute $4$ candies, with some kid(s) possibly getting $0$ candies, is $\binom{6}{2}$.

The same argument works in general. We want to find the number of solutions in non-negative integers of the equation $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_k=n$. So we want to find the number of ways to distribute $n$ candies among $k$ kids. Look instead at the number of ways to distribute $n+k$ candies among $k$ kids, with each kid getting at least $1$ candy. There are then $n+k-1$ intercandy gaps, and I must choose $k-1$ of these gaps to put a separator into. There are $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for integer sums of the kind you asked this is a general reasoning.

You form the word with +'s and |'s  and then you count how many anagrams you can obtain for this strange word of +'s and |'

In your case there are 6 words. 4 +'s and 2 |'s.

The total number of anagrams is $$\frac{6!}{4!2!} = {6 \choose 4}$$

I rather think in terms of anagrams, since it carries on easily to other kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence
$$*\mid *\mid **$$
We can represent this sequence in another way by associating each element with its ordinal position
$$(*,1), (\mid, 2), (*,3), (\mid,4),(*,5),(*,6)$$
So the problem of counting the number of  arrangements of 4 stars and 2 bars becomes equivalent to counting the number of ways to choose 2 ordinal positions for the bars from a set of 6 possible ordinal positions. This is identical to counting the number of subsets of size 2 from a set of size 6, or $\displaystyle\binom 6 2$.